# query does not return all expected rows

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT p.INVOICE_PAYMENT_ID,i.INVOICE_ID,i.INVOICE_NUMBER,i.CLINIC_ID,
    i.INVOICE_DATE,i.PAYMENT_RECEIVED_DATE, i.AMOUNT,
    i.CURRENT_CHARGE,i.AMOUNT_RECEIVED,i.MONTH,i.YEAR,i.COMPANY_ID,
    i.COMPANY_NAME,c.NAME,p.NOTE,i.NOTES
FROM test1 i 
LEFT JOIN test2 c ON (i.CLINIC_ID=c.CLINIC_ID)
LEFT JOIN test3 p ON p.INVOICE_ID=i.INVOICE_ID  
WHERE i.MONTH=11 AND i.YEAR=2011                     
    AND  p.INVOICE_PAYMENT_ID IN (
        SELECT MAX(INVOICE_PAYMENT_ID) 
        FROM test3 WHERE INVOICE_ID=i.INVOICE_ID 
    )
```

If the inner query has no value then it does not return all the corresponding rows in `test3`.

How do I fix this?

Comment: If the inner query has no value then there AREN'T any corresponding rows in `test3`. What do you expect to happen?

Comment: @jinesh indeed, what do you expect? (I assume the inner query is the one with `max`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move your inner query from `where` clause to `join` condition:

```
SELECT p.INVOICE_PAYMENT_ID,i.INVOICE_ID,i.INVOICE_NUMBER,i.CLINIC_ID,
    i.INVOICE_DATE,i.PAYMENT_RECEIVED_DATE, i.AMOUNT,
    i.CURRENT_CHARGE,i.AMOUNT_RECEIVED,i.MONTH,i.YEAR,i.COMPANY_ID,
    i.COMPANY_NAME,c.NAME,p.NOTE,i.NOTES
FROM test1 i 
LEFT JOIN test2 c ON (i.CLINIC_ID=c.CLINIC_ID)
LEFT JOIN test3 p ON p.INVOICE_ID=i.INVOICE_ID and p.INVOICE_PAYMENT_ID = (
        SELECT MAX(INVOICE_PAYMENT_ID) 
        FROM test3 WHERE INVOICE_ID=i.INVOICE_ID)
WHERE i.MONTH=11 AND i.YEAR=2011
```

Comment: As a minor adjustment, if you are expecting there to always be records in `test2` for each row in `test1` (i.e. there will always be a `c.NAME` for every invoice row, then you may wish to change that join to be `INNER JOIN test2 c ....` as generally it'd perform slightly more efficiently :)

Answer (score 0):

You can change your actual where clause:

```
... AND 
    p.INVOICE_PAYMENT_ID IN 
    (SELECT MAX(INVOICE_PAYMENT_ID) 
     FROM test3 WHERE INVOICE_ID=i.INVOICE_ID )
```

by:

```
... AND
(
    not exists 
    (SELECT MAX(INVOICE_PAYMENT_ID) 
    FROM test3 WHERE INVOICE_ID=i.INVOICE_ID ) 
 OR
    p.INVOICE_PAYMENT_ID IN 
    (SELECT MAX(INVOICE_PAYMENT_ID) 
     FROM test3 WHERE INVOICE_ID=i.INVOICE_ID )
)
```

This will returns test3 also if there are no data for this montn and condition.